# how to create table in Google BigQuery from continuously uploaded Kafka text files into Google cloud storage

Tags: apache-kafka, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

i want to create bigquery table from the cloud storage. Kafka steam uploaded as text files into Cloud storage by every 5 minutes. I want to create bigquery table using that is updating every 5 minutes from the updated files into Bigquery. What is the best way to do this? Please give me some suggestions

Comment: I would recommend to start with [this](https://medium.com/myheritage-engineering/kafka-to-bigquery-load-a-guide-for-streaming-billions-of-daily-events-cbbf31f4b737) article. Can you get any benefit from there in the current research?

Comment: @mk_sta  Yes. it's really useful. thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [google-cloud-functions](/questions/tagged/google-cloud-functions) to detect when a file is uploaded, then execute some code to index that file.

Alternatively, I believe there already exists a BigQuery Kafka Connector, so you could skip GCS unless you need the raw data. (Note: binary files would be cheaper to store than plaintext, and BigQuery supports reading various formats)